# How do I add semicolons to SQL statements?

Tags: text-processing, sed

Say I have this (with the format I show, no newlines)

```
INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (1) INSERT INTO `somthing` (`somethingelse`) VALUES ('something with a (paranthesis) in it') INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (3) INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (4)
```

I want the output to be

```
INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (1); INSERT INTO `somthing` (`somethingelse`) VALUES ('something with a (paranthesis) in it'); INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (3); INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (4);
```

So that they are legitimate SQL queries. I have tried this in sed:

```
sed 's/\(VALUES ([^)]*)\)/\1;/g')
```

Which works, except when there are parantheses inside the values, I am not sure what do to to fix that. Basically, I want add a semicolon to the end of `(.*)`, (the last `)`) if it says `VALUES` before it.

Comment: To make your sample input useful, please include a part for which the sed code fails.  And, of course, include the corresponding sample output for that case as well.

Comment: @John1024 Ok, did that now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple pattern that will be correct in every circumstance; you would need to write a SQL parser to determine when the end of statement *should* be... and even then you'd need to hope there's no special magic happening.  Now ANSI SQL isn't Turing Complete (although extensions may be) so you probably *could* write a parser...

Or you could write a stack-based parser to add a `;` after a closing `)`... and handle bad syntax.

Instead you might want to use something more likely to fail to match erronously.  For example, this code picks up on the `INSERT INTO` statement and puts a `;` in front of that, remembering to add one at the very end.

```
sed -e 's/\( INSERT INTO `somthing` (`something`) VALUES (\)/;\1/g' -e 's/$/;/'
```

Obviously it would fail if the inserted data had that specific string...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by matching a different part of the statement, e.g.,

```
sed -e 's/\(VALUES (`[^`]*`)\)/\1;/g' \
    -e "s/\(VALUES ('[^']*')\)/\1;/g" \
    -e 's/\(VALUES ([0-9]*)\)/\1;/g'
```

That will not depend on what is inside the parentheses.

Comment: The `.*` will be greedy and match too far.  Other than that, we had the same idea :-)

Comment: He does; that's the problem.  The example provided has 4 `INSERT` statements on one line with no obvious delineation between them.

Comment: I think this final version passes the tests :-)  That was hard work!

Comment: Oh, except for a final `;` on the last statement, which is easy to add :-)

Comment: you can use `\0` or `&` and avoid the use of `\( \)`

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming that the ending `)` of `VALUES` will be followed by `INSERT` keyword or end of line, as given in sample input provided in question

```
perl -pe 's/VALUES\s*\(.*?\)(?=\s*INSERT|$)/$&;/g' file
```

2) Assuming there are two ways `VALUES` can be present:

- VALUES without inner `()` won't have `'` in them
- VALUES with inner `()` will start as `('` and end with `')`

```
perl -pe "s/VALUES\s*\([^')]*\)/$&;/g ; s/VALUES\s*\('.*?'\)/$&;/g" file
```